# PySpark : How to remove all numbers then find the most common value in an array column?

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark

I'm trying to isolate the most common postcode area from an array column containing the postcode outcode (uk postcodes) in PySpark.

Here is an eg of how the column looks, excluding the other columns in the df which I want to keep as they are (these are random made up values):

```
| postcode_outcde | 
| --------------- | 
| [SN00],[SN01],[OA77] | 
| [FG12],[PC00],[PD01],[FG99]| 
| [WP55] | 
| [DD01],[DD02] |
```

And then the result I want:

```
| postcode_area   |
| --------------- |
| SN              |
| FG              |     
| WP              |
| DD              |
```

I can only figure out how to remove the numbers by converting to a sting then removing digits with regex. I've been trying to find the most common value by using explode, groupby and window etc but I need it to be an array for this so converting to string to remove the numbers isn't practical. I also can't seem to figure out how to write the code for this so it works.

I'm new to PySpark so I'm struggling

Comment: what if all postcodes have different postcode areas? or 2 postcode areas have same number of occurrence? also why is your example like `[SN00],[SN01],[OA77]`? is the column array of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I did it without exploding the dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ([['SN00'], ['SN01'], ['QA77']],),
    ([['FG12'], ['PC00'], ['PD01'], ['FG99']],),
    ([['WP55']],),
    ([['DD01'], ['DD02']],)
], ['postcode_outcde'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('postcode_areas', f.expr("transform(flatten(postcode_outcde), x -> substring(x, 1, 2))"))
    .withColumn('postcode_areas_counts', f.expr("transform(postcode_areas, element -> size(filter(postcode_areas, val -> val = element)))"))
    .withColumn('most_common_postcode', f.expr('element_at(postcode_areas, cast(array_position(postcode_areas_counts, array_max(postcode_areas_counts)) as int))'))
    .select(df['*'], 'most_common_postcode')
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

and the output is:

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------+                         
|postcode_outcde                 |most_common_postcode|
+--------------------------------+--------------------+
|[[SN00], [SN01], [QA77]]        |SN                  |
|[[FG12], [PC00], [PD01], [FG99]]|FG                  |
|[[WP55]]                        |WP                  |
|[[DD01], [DD02]]                |DD                  |
+--------------------------------+--------------------+
```